# user disappeared during update error

Tags: freebsd

I did a upgrade to FreeBSD 9 a few weeks ago and just started using it, and when I try and create a new user, I get the follow:

```
pw: user 'todd' disappeared during update
adduser: ERROR: There was an error adding user (todd).
```

I first noticed this issue when trying to install postfix and got a similar error.

Anyone know what this is or how to fix it without a complete re-install?

Some people have suggested shutting down the nscd daemon, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you try to regenerate your password database with vipw? Some people reported this error, when /etc/passwd and /etc/master.passwd got out of sync

Comment: This fixed the error when I was upgrading from 10.3 to 11, during the `pkg update` step to rebuild all installed ports.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd`